# What does sklearn's pairwise_distances with metric='correlation' do?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pairwise-distance

I've put different values into this function and observed the output. But I can't find a predictable pattern in what is being outputed.

Then I tried digging through the [function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e9/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py#L1316) itself, but its confusing because it can do a number of different calculations.

**According to the [Docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html):**

```
Compute the distance matrix from a vector array X and optional Y.
```

I see it returns a matrix of height and width equal to the number of nested lists inputted, implying that it is comparing each one.

But otherwise I'm having a tough time understanding what its doing and where the values are coming from.

**Examples I've tried:**

```
pairwise_distances([[1]], metric='correlation')
>>> array([[0.]])

pairwise_distances([[1], [1]], metric='correlation')
>>> array([[ 0., nan],
>>>        [nan,  0.]])

# returns same as last input although input values differ
pairwise_distances([[1], [2]], metric='correlation')
>>> array([[ 0., nan],
>>>        [nan,  0.]])

pairwise_distances([[1,2], [1,2]], metric='correlation')
>>> array([[0.00000000e+00, 2.22044605e-16],
>>>        [2.22044605e-16, 0.00000000e+00]])

# returns same as last input although input values differ
# I incorrectly expected more distance because input values differ more
pairwise_distances([[1,2], [1,3]], metric='correlation')
>>> array([[0.00000000e+00, 2.22044605e-16],
>>>       [2.22044605e-16, 0.00000000e+00]])
```

**Computing correlation distance with Scipy**

I don't understand where the sklearn `2.22044605e-16` value is coming from if scipy returns `0.0` for the same inputs.

```
# Scipy
import scipy
scipy.spatial.distance.correlation([1,2], [1,2])
>>> 0.0

# Sklearn
pairwise_distances([[1,2], [1,2]], metric='correlation')
>>> array([[0.00000000e+00, 2.22044605e-16],
>>>        [2.22044605e-16, 0.00000000e+00]])
```

I'm not looking for a high level explanation but an example of how the numbers are calculated.

Comment: as others have stated 2.22e-16 *is* 0 for all intensive purposes as floats in python are not more precise than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pairwise_distances` internally call the `distance.pdist()`, when `y` is `None`(which means we want to compute the distance matrix for each vector in X)

Reference [1](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e9/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py#L1428), [2](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.2.1/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L182)

The implementation would be similar to the following:

```
X = np.array([[1,2], [1,2]])

import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm

X2 = X - X.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)

u, v =[*X2]

1 - (sum(u*v)/(norm(u) * norm(v)))

#2.220446049250313e-16
```

But `scipy.spatial.distance.correlation` implementation differs in the latest version

[latest version](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.2.1/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L659), [old version](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L300)

If we set the weights to None, the following snippet is the simplified version of it:

```
u, v = np.array([1,2]), np.array([1,2])

umu = np.average(u)
vmu = np.average(v)
u = u - umu
v = v - vmu
uv = np.average(u * v)
uu = np.average(np.square(u))
vv = np.average(np.square(v))
dist = 1.0 - uv / np.sqrt(uu * vv)
dist

#0
```

Answer (score 1):

The distance metrics can be found here:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html

And correlation is specifically here:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.correlation.html#scipy.spatial.distance.correlation

The correlation distance between u and v, is defined as

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I added a part about trying `scipy.spatial.distance.correlation()`. Getting different values than with sklearn so I still think I'm missing something major.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import sklearn

X = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 4, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1]]

D = sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances(X, metric='correlation')
print(D)
```

Output:

```
[[0.         0.10557281 2.        ]
 [0.10557281 0.         1.89442719]
 [2.         1.89442719 0.        ]]
```

`D` is a distance matrix such that *D<sub>{i, j}</sub>* is the distance between the i<sup>th</sup> and j<sup>th</sup> vectors of the given matrix `X`.

```
import scipy

X = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 4, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1]]

c_00 = scipy.spatial.distance.correlation(X[0], X[0])        # c_00 = 0.0
c_01 = scipy.spatial.distance.correlation(X[0], X[1])        # c_01 = 0.10557280900008414
c_02 = scipy.spatial.distance.correlation(X[0], X[2])        # c_02 = 2.0
```

---

> I don't understand where the sklearn `2.22044605e-16` value is coming from if scipy returns `0.0` for the same inputs.

This is probably a [round-off error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

```
import numpy as np
epsilon = np.finfo(float).eps
print(epsilon)
```

Outputs:

```
2.220446049250313e-16                                    # This value is machine dependent
```

You could use [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) to round extremely small values to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I totally understand the confusion.

Correlation is calulated on vectors, and sklearn did a non-trivial conversion of a scalar to a vector of size 1.

the result of

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
from scipy.spatial.distance import correlation
pairwise_distances([u,v,w], metric='correlation')
```

Is a matrix `M` of shape `(len([u,v,w]),len([u,v,w]))=(3,3)`, where:

```
M[0,0] = correlation(u,u)
M[0,1] = correlation(u,v)
M[0,2] = correlation(u,w)
M[1,0] = correlation(v,u)
M[1,1] = correlation(v,v)
M[1,2] = correlation(v,w)
M[2,0] = correlation(w,u)
M[2,1] = correlation(w,v)
M[2,2] = correlation(w,w)
```

you were looking at `correlation([u,v,w], [u,v,w])` that has a valid value only if `u` ,`v` and `w` are scalars.